# React Formik compare values and initual values

Tags: reactjs, compare, formik

I have searched and dont know where to look. How do you compare the initual values and your values in formik and when there is a difrence get the name of that value where the difrence is.

Tried this link but no luck https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/215

if there is a new value for username when you update it , I want to know username updated .

```
<Formik
            innerRef={formRef}
            enableReinitialize={true}
            initialValues={{
                //General
                id: currentUserData.id || '',
                username: currentUserData.username || '',
                name: currentUserData.name || '',
                surname: currentUserData.surname || '',
                dob: currentUserData.dob || '',
                position: currentUserData.position || '',
                notificationValue: currentUserData.notificationValue || 0,

                email: currentUserData.email || '',
                contactNo: currentUserData.contactNo || '',
                userRolls: currentUserData.userRolls || userRolls  ,
                status: currentUserData.status || 'Active',
                

                
            }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there is no straight forward way to achieve this.
To achieve this comparison, You need to first store the initial values in local variable or state and use as shown in the below code.

```
const initalValues = {
  //General
  id: currentUserData.id || "",
  username: currentUserData.username || "",
  name: currentUserData.name || "",
  surname: currentUserData.surname || "",
  dob: currentUserData.dob || "",
  position: currentUserData.position || "",
  notificationValue: currentUserData.notificationValue || 0,

  email: currentUserData.email || "",
  contactNo: currentUserData.contactNo || "",
  userRolls: currentUserData.userRolls || userRolls,
  status: currentUserData.status || "Active",
};


   <Formik
      initialValues={initalValues}
      enableReinitialize={true}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        const keys = Object.keys(initalValues);

        keys.map((key) => {       
          if (initalValues[key] != values[key]) {
            console.log(key);  // Your field name which is modified       
          }
        });
      }}
    >
```